# Widget Testing being Failed in Flutter but Screen is Properly Rendering in each device after Upgrading flutter to 1.9.1

Tags: testing, flutter, widget

Can you help me with this? All screens are rendering properly in device but when pumping Widget tests are being failed. with

```
    The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 0.966 pixels on the bottom.

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
  Container
  file:///Users/---/lib/presentation/profile_personal/profile_personal_screen.dart:89:16

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#c07df OVERFLOWING:
  needs compositing
  creator: Column ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Padding ← Column ←
    _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#da8d9] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ←
    ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(1.0, 1.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=727.6, h=29.0)
  size: Size(727.6, 29.0)
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: center
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

Comment: There is some issue. Flex is overflowing but as the overflow is less than 1 pixel you are not able to see it. If you inspect "profile_personal_screen" may be you can find some dynamic values which main increasing the layout size at the time of testing.

Comment: how can i figure out which widget is overflowing

Comment: Currently I can see only this
`User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
  Container
  file:///Users/---/lib/presentation/profile_personal/profile_personal_screen.dart:89:16`
So it should be some container as per my thinking. Or share some code so we can help more.

Comment: I'm facing this issue after upgrading flutter